AVX512 assembly breaks when called concurrently from different goroutines
I have a custom piece of golang (1.23.0) assembly which performs AVX512 operations to speed up a very common code path. The function checks to see if a group of players are holding a poker hand by representing hands as int64 bitsets. The code looks like this (a CardSet is simply an int64):
// func SubsetAVX512(cs []CardSet, hs []CardSet) int
// Returns 1 if any card set in cards contains any hand in hands, 0 otherwise

#include "textflag.h"

#define cs_data 0(FP)
#define cs_len  8(FP)
#define cs_cap  16(FP)
#define hs_data 24(FP)
#define hs_len  32(FP)
#define hs_cap  40(FP)
#define ret_off 48(FP)

// Define the function
TEXT ·SubsetAVX512(SB), NOSPLIT, $0-56

// Start of the function
    // Load parameters into registers
    MOVQ cs+cs_data, R8         // R8 = cards_ptr
    MOVQ cs+cs_len, R9          // R9 = cards_len

    MOVQ hs+hs_data, R10        // R10 = hands_ptr
    MOVQ hs+hs_len, R11         // R11 = hands_len

    // Check if hands_len == 0
    TESTQ R11, R11
    JE return_false

    // Check if cards_len == 0
    TESTQ R9, R9
    JE return_false

    // Initialize loop counters
    XORQ R12, R12                 // R12 = i = 0 (hands index)

    // Main loop over hands
outer_loop:
    CMPQ R12, R11                 // Compare i (R12) with hands_len (R11)
    JGE return_false              // If i >= hands_len, no match found

    // Load 8 hands into Z0 (512-bit register)
    LEAQ (R10)(R12*8), R13        // R13 = &hands[i]
    VMOVDQU64 0(R13), Z0          // Load 8 int64s from [R13] into Z0

    // Inner loop over cards
    XORQ R14, R14                 // R14 = j = 0 (cards index)
inner_loop:
    CMPQ R14, R9                  // Compare j (R14) with cards_len (R9)
    JGE next_hands_block          // If j >= cards_len, move to next hands block

    // Load cs from cards[j]
    LEAQ (R8)(R14*8), R15         // R15 = &cards[j]
    MOVQ 0(R15), AX               // AX = cards[j]

    // Broadcast cs into Z1
    VPBROADCASTQ AX, Z1           // Broadcast RAX into all lanes of Z1

    // Compute cs_vec & h_vec
    VPANDQ Z0, Z1, Z2             // Z2 = Z0 & Z1

    // Compare (cs_vec & h_vec) == h_vec
    VPCMPEQQ Z0, Z2, K1           // Compare Z0 == Z2, store result in mask K1

    // Check if any comparison is true
    KORTESTW K1, K1               // Test if any bits in K1 are set
    JNZ found_match               // If so, a match is found

    // Increment card index
    INCQ R14                      // j++
    JMP inner_loop                // Repeat inner loop

next_hands_block:
    // Increment hands index by 8
    ADDQ $8, R12                  // i += 8
    JMP outer_loop                // Repeat outer loop

found_match:
    // Match found, return 1
    MOVQ $1, AX                   // Set return value to 1 (true)
    RET

return_false:
    // No match found, return 0
    XORQ AX, AX                   // Set return value to 0 (false)
    RET

This code works great as long as it's not called concurrently, this works:
type CardSet int64
func SubsetAVX512(cs, hs []CardSet) bool
func TestSubsetAVX512(t *testing.T) {
    cs := []CardSet{3, 1}
    hs := []CardSet{3, 0}
    var count int64
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        if SubsetAVX512(cs, hs) {
            atomic.AddInt64(&count, 1)
        }
    }
    require.Equal(t, int64(5), count)
}

however, this fails:
type CardSet int64
func SubsetAVX512(cs, hs []CardSet) bool
func TestSubsetAVX512(t *testing.T) {
    cs := []CardSet{3, 1}
    hs := []CardSet{3, 0}
    var count int64
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            if SubsetAVX512(cs, hs) {
                atomic.AddInt64(&count, 1)
            }
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    require.Equal(t, int64(5), count)
}

I believe that the issue has to do with some of the registers I'm using being overwritten by concurrent goroutines. My guess is it's the mask register K1 but that's just a slightly educated guess.

Switching to a different Go routine should save all registers of the current Go routine.  What version of the Go toolchain do you use?

Go 1.23.0, I believe it doesn't save mask registers since they're not normally used. But again not sure about that.

Go explicitly supports programming in AVX-512 and that includes use of mask registers.  What bothers me about your code is that you don't do a VZEROUPPER before returning.  While that should not break your code, it will cause performance issues in other code using SSE instructions.

Thanks for the tip, I added VZEROUPPER in both of the return paths. As expected it doesn't fix the bug but sounds like that's best practice and will give me better overall performance.

Your problem is that you try to return a result in AX when the Go calling convention requires you to return results on the stack.  Change the return to use
MOVQ $1, ret+ret_off

to properly return a result and you'll see your problems disappear.

A dumb question, please. ISTR, since 1.17 the gc make of Go was in the process of gradually switching to the register-based calling convention. Does this affect assembly code, or does the compiler make sure these functions follow the original stack-based CC?

@kostix Assembly functions are not affected by the ABI change; they'll continue to use the same ABI as always.  The linker transparently deals with the difference.

Didn't the Go team make excuses that performance wasn't very important, and they could fix it later?  Well here we are, and people are using asm for performance reasons and are still stuck with an inefficient calling convention.  ABI design decisions are a huge pain to change; don't be short-sighted about it.  (And good calling conventions already existed on modern ISAs.)  To be slightly fair, call overhead means you always want to write a whole loop in asm, not wrapping single instructions, but still, small arrays exist.

@PeterCordes Yeah, you should ensure there are few transitions between assembly and Go code.  That said, with store-forwarding, stack based calling conventions are not that bad.

"Assembly functions are not affected by the ABI change" — It would be great if you could point to some public documentation about that. I could only find this sentence in the Go 1.17 release notes: "To maintain compatibility with existing assembly functions, the compiler generates adapter functions that convert between the new register-based calling convention and the previous stack-based calling convention.". But then, as the OP's case shows, the compiler expects hand-written asm functions to follow the old ABI...?

@blackgreen Yes, correct.  Hand-written asm functions always follow the stable ABI0 as always.  See Go Internal ABI Specification and the Internal ABI Proposal for details.
